# Eclipse MAT

Tags: android, eclipse

"Eclipse Memory Analyzer это хорошая утилита для анализа выделений памяти. Она поможет вам найти утечки памяти в вашем приложении." Объясните мне пожалуйста, как использовать эту утилиту. Никак не разберусь.

Comment: Вам для андроида или для java декстопно-серверной?

Comment: Для андроида

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашла 2 ссылки, которые всё объясняют. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112671/android-memory-analysing-eclipse-memory-analyzer
Отсюда видно, что надо запустить debug приложения, открыть DDMS в Eclipse. Во вкладке Devices выбрать устройство и пакет вашего устройства. Затем нажать на кнопку "Dump HPROF file" во вкладке Devices, таким образом вы создадите файл с необходимым разрешением. Затем в Eclipse MAT откройте File->Open Heap Dump, выберите свой файл. Если он не загрузится, то проблема скорее всего в этом:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219049/error-openning-hprof-file
Здесь нужно в командной строке ввести следующую команду:
hprof-conv android.hprof mat.hprof,
где bycnhevty hprof-conv лежит в папке AndrodiSDK/tools/hprof-conv. Вобщем в ссылках всё есть. Далее открываете свой файл в МАТ и анализируете)

Answer (score 0):

Могу рассказать из личного опыта. 
Пользовался этой штукой сам давненько как-то. Профилировал Android-приложение.

В коде приложения нужно вызвать:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#dumpHprofData(java.lang.String)

Метод записывает данные в формате hprov, но формат который не схавает MAT. Запишет данные в указанный файл на карту памяти.

Чтобы MAT понял формат нужно сконверировать полученный файл с помощью стандартной утилиты в SDK: 
    hprof-conv dump.hprof converted-dump.hprof

После сконвертированный файл уже можно открыть с помощью Eclipse MAT.
Просмотреть сколько какой метод выполнялся и т.д.

Комплексное чтиво тут:
http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html